# Is there a jQuery event that can trigger *after* an anchor click completes?

Tags: jquery, events

Here's one for ya!

Is there some kind of jQuery event that will fire *after* an anchor click event completes rather than prior?

I want the user to click the `<a href="/someurl" target="_blank">link</a>` and then have the new tab open accordingly, but then on the current page (not new tab) and after that new tab opens, redirect to another page. So I was looking for an event in which to do this.

However as it stands it seems that the event happens prior to the anchor tag click finishing its business, however a redirect at that stage would interrupt the anchor click.

Note: The reason I am using "_blank" on the anchor click browser action for the new page so that the browser pop-up blockers won't get in the way as they do when you invoke such a thing via javascript.

Comment: Popup blockers are there for a reason. Try redesigning your solution using jQuery UI dialog for example.

Comment: @JakubKonecki Pop-up blockers don't block if the user clicks a link that has target="_blank", my note was to clarify why I was using this method.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you have the `click` event call a method which in turn calls the `setTimeout` method with a delegate to change the `document.location`?

Comment: This may be the answer, but I was hoping there would be an event I could use so that I wouldn't have to rely on a time based solution.

Comment: @Alexander - Any answer which circumvents a pop-up blocker behavior is going to be a workaround.

Comment: @SpencerRuport I am not circumventing a pop-up blocker... I am trying to redirect a page prior to finishing a standard browser acceptable anchor tag target="_blank" click, without having that event lost after redirect... I must have done a bad job writing this question because everyone keeps saying this.

Comment: Ryan - I understand what you're trying to do but the fact is that the "real" way to do this would be to have javascript open a new window and change the location of the current page. Pop-up blockers do not allow this so, at least the way I see it, any method you use that gets around this would be circumventing the pop-up blocker. That said, I don't think what you're trying to accomplish goes against the spirit of pop-up blocking which is why I'm willing to offer suggestions. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `click` handler and `return true;`. This won't stop the browser from processing the actual click.

Comment: Right, but if I do a redirect of the current page prior to 'return true' won't it prevent return true from happening?

Comment: Hmmm, probably yes... - timeout workaround may be your only hope ;-)